# Program returns all permutations of n elements?infinite loop?

Tags: c, algorithm

This code should output all permutations of n elements, So when i enter for example 3 Output it must :

`ABC
 BAC
 CAB
 ACB
 BCA
 CBA`

with this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *x, char *y){
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}
void permute(char *a, int l, int r){
  int i;
  if (l == r)
    printf("%s\n", a);
  else
  {
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++){
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(a, l+1, r);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); 

    }
  }
}
int main(){
  int x , n ;
  int i = 0 ;
  char str[26];
  printf("prem ");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  while (x > 0){
    str[i] = 'A' + i ;
    i++;
    x--;
  }
  n = strlen(str);
  permute(str, 0, n-1);

}
```

I should type what I want for a number eg 3 for ABC or 4 for ABCD and then the code should handle that but it didnt workea and it goes in an infinite loop

but for this Code  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *x, char *y){
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}
void permute(char *a, int l, int r){
  int i;
  if (l == r)
    printf("%s\n", a);
  else
  {
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++){
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(a, l+1, r);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); 

    }
  }
}
int main()
{
  char str[26];
  gets(str);
  int n = strlen(str);
  permute(str, 0, n-1);
  return 0;
}
```

I can enter whatever i want and it handle with it without Problem

**my question is what is the problem with the first code? i mean i want to enter a number so that the program: if i type 3 for example it should deal with ABC**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main should be like:

```
int main(){
  int x , n ;
  int i = 0 ;
  char str[26];
  printf("prem ");
  scanf("%d",&x);

  //user entered the string length in x, let' save it in n
  n = x;

  while (x > 0){
    str[i] = 'A' + i ;
    i++;
    x--;
  }

  //n = strlen(str); ===> this is wrong, the user did not entered a string

  permute(str, 0, n-1);
}
```

In the working code (the second block of code you posted), the user enters a string which is stored in `str` variable:

```
gets(str);
```

Then the string length is passed to `permute` function using `strlen`:

```
int n = strlen(str);
permute(str, 0, n-1);
```

In the first (non working) block of code, you ask the user to enter a length, not a string, and store it in `x`. You then put `x` characters in `str` array, but this is not a proper *c string*, because a null terminator is missing. So `strlen` return value is pretty much unreliable.

If you don't like the solution I suggested, you can just provide a

```
str[i] = '\0';
```

right after your `while` block and leave everything else untouched, and it will work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `strlen` is invoked on a string which is not terminated.

**Either** add `'\0'` at the end of the string to terminal it:

```
while (x > 0){
    str[i] = 'A' + i ;
    i++;
    x--;
}
str[i] = '\0';
```

**OR** (better)

invoke `permute` with the original value of `x` (save it after the `scanf`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the str string is not properly terminated therefore result of `n = strlen(str);` is undefined. `strlen` counts characters till `\0` is encountered.

```
int main(){
int x , n ;
int i = 0 ;
char str[26];
printf("prem ");
scanf("%d",&x);
while (x > 0){
    str[i] = 'A' + i ;
    i++;
    x--;
}

str[i] = 0; // terminate the string

n = strlen(str);
permute(str, 0, n-1);

}
```